# Google Map Markers does not appear in $.getJSON Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-markers

I am reading from a JSON file to plot my latitude and longitude onto Google Maps. I have tried using different approaches but nothing showed up. For this approach, the map showed but the markers are not there.

```
//this is my json file: out1copy.json
[{
  "GPSLatitude": "1.306279",
  "GPSLongitude": "103.904783",
  "Title": "Joo Chiat Road"
},
{
  "GPSLatitude": "1.343176",
  "GPSLongitude": "103.851983",
  "Title": "Braddell Road"
},
{
  "GPSLatitude": "1.318105",
  "GPSLongitude": "103.766597",
  "Title": "Clementi Avenue"
},
{
  "GPSLatitude": "1.427895",
  "GPSLongitude": "103.837806",
  "Title": "Yishun Central"
}]
```

This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Try (Markers gone)</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var map;
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.3667, 103.8);
var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

$.getJSON('out1copy.json', function(data){ 
    $.each(data.markers, function(i, item) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.GPSLatitude,item.GPSLongitude);
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        });
    });        
});

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Where could have gone wrong?

Comment: I have tested all parts of your code except the JSON call - http://jsfiddle.net/Rkj8T/1/ do you see any console errors? Can you see the request occur in the networks tab of your developer tools?

Comment: @JonathanCrowe The markers finally works!! Can you explain to me why there is 2 var latlng? When calling the .json file, it always fail without showing the errors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the dom to load before running your map functions:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
    var map;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.3667, 103.8);
    var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 11,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    $.getJSON('out1copy.json', function(data){ 
        $.each(data.markers, function(i, item) {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.GPSLatitude,item.GPSLongitude);
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
            });
        });        
    });

});
```

Comment: I have edited it but my markers are still not there.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle? That would definitely help debug

Comment: Also - your closing </head> should be just before your opening <body> tag. that could be causing some strangeness

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with fiddle. But this is my results http://jsfiddle.net/Rkj8T/

Comment: @itnoobrm did you try fixing the location of your closing </head> tag?

Comment: Yes I edited that but the results is still the same.